# sliding login form

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, overflow

When I click a certain trigger... I want to slide in a simple login form.  I have this part working (for the most part)... but am having trouble with some JS and display properties.

Display:
I only want to see this form in the containing div.  Right now it appears outside the containing div and then slides in.  If I try to resolve this with an overflow property... the close button does not show up.  I tried playing with both z-index and overflow.

JS:
I am setting an active class when the trigger is clicked... but am unable to remove this class when the close button is clicked.  Also... I would like the form to slide back out when the close button is clicked.

Here's a quick and dirty JSFiddle of what I have.  You may need to expand this out so you can see how the for appears outside of the containing div when the trigger is clicked... and then slides in.

[JSFiddle][1]

http://jsfiddle.net/Rule13/fjb5R/

### Here's the code:

CSS

```
<style>
body,td,th {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
.row {width:978px; margin:50px auto;}

.loginRow {position:relative;}
.loginTrigger {
    background-color:#fff;
    background-image:url(img/bgLoginCheckout.png); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-transition: background-position 0.3s linear; 
     -moz-transition: background-position 0.3s linear; 
       -o-transition: background-position 0.3s linear; 
          transition: background-position 0.3s linear; 
    background-position: 2px 5px; 
    padding-left:34px; 
    cursor:pointer; 
    position:relative;
    width:190px;
    float:left;
    z-index:1000;
}
.loginTriggerText {min-height:27px;}
    h3 {margin:0; padding:0;}
    h5 {margin:0; padding:0; margin-top:-3px; font-weight:normal;}

.loginTrigger:hover {
    background-position:2px -85px;
    color:#08e;
}
.loginTriggerActive {
    background-position:2px -85px;
    color:#08e;
    cursor:text;
}
.loginTriggerClose {
    position:absolute;
    top:-8px;
    left: -16px;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:none;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#000;
}
.loginForm {
    width:700px;
    float:left;
    margin-top: 8px;
    display: none; 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    left: -300px;
    z-index:100;
}
label {margin-right:14px;}
</style>
```

HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col12">
    <div class="loginRow">
      <div class="loginTrigger">
        <div class="loginTriggerText">
          <h3>Have an account?</h3>
          <h5>Login here for faster checkout.</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="loginTriggerClose">
          X
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="loginForm">
        <label for="email">Email <input id="email" type="email" ></label> <label for="password">Password <input id="password" type="password"></label> <input type="submit" value="Login">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    $('.loginTriggerClose').hide();
    var loginForm = $('.loginForm');

    $('.loginTrigger').click(function() {
        $(this).addClass('loginTriggerActive');
        $('.loginTriggerClose').delay(500).show();
        $(loginForm).show();
        $(loginForm).stop().animate({ "left": "260px" }, 800, function(){ 

        });

    });

    $('.loginTriggerClose').click(function() {
        $(this).fadeOut();
        //$('.loginTrigger').removeClass('loginTriggerActive');     
        $(loginForm).stop().animate({ "left": "-300px" }, 800, function() { 
            $(loginForm).hide(); 
        });
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Seems to work for me. Maybe I am confused with what you want.

Comment: i dont get it , as @twodayslate it is working .. please explain more

Comment: Thanks for looking at this.  The form slides in from the left and the active class gets appended.  That part works.  But I don;t want the form visible outside of the container... and I want to slide the form back out when the close button is clicked... as well as remove the active class from the trigger.

You may need to expand your window to see the form appearing outside of the containing div.